# Compare values in column, return a value based on what is in the columns

Tags: sql

I have a table that has 3 columns, ID, Record and signed....  ID is unique but RecordID duplicates because each row is identifying if someone signed off on something in the record.  The 3rd column is if they signed off on it or not.
Below is an example of what the table could look like.

What I'm trying to do is return a 1 if the record is completely signed off on or or a 0 if the record isn't completely signed off on....

[Here is an example of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZyKE.jpg)

`My output should be like this 5099 =0, 5100 = 0, 5101 = 1, 5102 = 0`

I've been racking my head on it

I've tried the following code and it seems to work on items that have more than two rows.  But if they have two rows and one signed is yes and the other no I'm getting a 1

```
select
    (case
    when not exists(
            select *
            From Table
            Where signed<> '' no) then 0

            Else '1'

     end);
```

my output should be like this 5099 =0, 5100 = 0, 5101 = 1, 5102 = 0

Comment: please edit the question and tag with database platform.  thanks

Comment: Most people here want sample table data (_and the expected result_) as formatted text, not as images..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this

```
select 
recordid, 
floor(avg(case when signed='yes' then 1 else 0 end)) as signed_status
from your_table
group by recordid;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b05df3b525b3dfe915107c510d343ac)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RecordID, CASE WHEN n_signed=n THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM
(
SELECT RecordID, SUM(CASE WHEN signed='yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as n_signed, COUNT(*) as n
FROM table
GROUP BY RecordID
) a
```